# How can I call alert while clicking on hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

My html code is pretty simple:

```
<a id="trigger-overlay" class="nav-toggle2" href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

and js is:

```
$(".nav-toggle2").click(function() {
    alert('gdsgdsfgs');
});
```

Why I don't see any alert msg when I click the link?

My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfwerce1/

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library

Comment: Doesn't look like you included jQuery in that fiddle.

Comment: When your Javascript doesn't work, the first thing you should do is check the Javascript console for errors. Only after you've exhausted all the debugging tools there should you post to SO.

Comment: It works fine if you select the jQuery library from the Frameworks menu: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jfwerce1/2/

Comment: advice ... if you use jquery.. your function should be wrapped by .ready or .load functions

Comment: Open console. View error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript you've posted is actually not pure ("vanilla") JavaScript. The syntax looks like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), which is a JavaScript library that allows you to more easily write event-driven JavaScript by providing a more consistent experience across older browsers and offering simpler syntax for common paradigms.

---

jQuery is great, but it only works if you include the library file. [This page](http://jquery.com/download/) discusses several ways to do that. On jsFiddle, you can actually just change the drop-down in the top-left "frameworks and extensions" category and include the latest version of jQuery automatically.

This code snippet below shows the script tag that you might use to include jQuery on your personal website.

```js
$(".nav-toggle2").click(function() {
    alert('gdsgdsfgs');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="trigger-overlay" class="nav-toggle2" href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

---

Importing a large library like jQuery will slow down the loading time of your page a little bit, and sometimes it is overkill. For simpler tasks, you may prefer to write the code in pure JavaScript so that you can avoid loading the jQuery library.

The task you're trying to do can be done like this without jQuery.

```js
document.getElementById('trigger-overlay').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('gdsgdsfgs');
});
```

```html
<a id="trigger-overlay" class="nav-toggle2" href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

---

In the future, be aware that you can use the JavaScript console to diagnose problems in your code. Accessing this console differs from browser-to-browser (in most browsers, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to access the developer tools, which usually has a JavaScript console in the bottom-most pane). Viewing it will show error messages and warnings when code is executed. For example, your code would display an error like "'$' is not a defined function." if executed without the jQuery library.

Comment: I almost want to upvote this answer for its utter clarity. But I wonder why the best and accepted answer would not point out the that the OP should view console errors, which would have shown him that `$` is not a function or whatever, and at least guided him towards solving more of the problem himself. I would also take umbrage at the simplistic characterization of jQuery as a "library that allows you to more easily write event-drive JavaScript". A fairer description would be a "library which provides compatibility for obsolete browsers, and some syntactic sugar".

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code with the jQuery library loaded:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfwerce1/1/

It does the same as:

```
<a id="trigger-overlay" class="nav-toggle2" href="#" onclick="alert('gdsgdsfgs');">Contact Us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go grab a copy of the jQuery library from jquery.com and include it right before your closing `</body>` tag.

Or just place this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

right there in the same space.

You may place this in your `<head>` as well, but typically its faster to just include before`</body>`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are suggesting you import jQuery (which would fix your code). However, if your page is indeed very simple you might as well keep it that way.

You can fix your code by using vanilla javascript by simply adding an onclick event to the anchor and creating a function in place of your current script.

```js
doSomething = function() {
    alert('gdsgdsfgs');
};
```

```html
<a id="trigger-overlay" class="nav-toggle2" href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Contact Us</a>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41x4b6qo/)

Comment: Sure, I appreciate the non-jQuery sentiment, but placing the handler directly on the element is so 2002. Show him the proper way to do it without jQuery in modern JS.

Comment: You know, that depends heavily on the architecture he's working with. You might consider AngularJS to be more "modern" than using jQuery to query the DOM for the element. And if that's the case you're still putting an ng-click on the element instead of querying it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an ancient library called "jQuery" which is bloated, inefficient, and unnecessary. It may be useful to know jQuery if your job is to maintain 10-year-old applications, but we now have better tools. Rewrite your code as

```
function onclick() { alert('gdsgdsfgs'); }

var elt = document.getElementById('trigger-overlay');
elt.addEventListener('click', onclick);
```

But wait a minute. That seems like a lot more code than the jQuery equivalent! Doesn't jQuery let me do the same thing in a single line? Yes, that's the crack-cocaine addictive nature of jQuery. But we can easily enough write our own utility routines, such as

```
function listen(id, event, handler) {
  document.getElementById(id) .  addEventListener(event, handler);
}
```

Once I've written that, all I need is

```
listen('trigger-overlay', 'click', onclick);
```

See, it's even shorter than jQuery.

But hey--I really liked those dollar signs! Can you give me some of those? Sure, how about two for the price of one? Let's just define

```
function $$click(id, handler) {
  document.getElementById(id) . addEventLister('click', handler);
}
```

Now I can write it an even shorter way!

```
$$click('trigger-overlay', onclick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop normal behavior of a (click) event in Javascript using `event.prefentDefault()`. Also note that the jquery click function callback also provides this `event`.

```
$(".nav-toggle2").click(function(event) {
    alert('gdsgdsfgs');
    event.prefentDefault();
});
```

This can be useful when:

- Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
- Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL defined in the "href".

MSDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault